# Convert string to type & pass to generic delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I've been puzzling at this for some time and I'm sure there's an elegant solution... I just can't seem to find it.

I have a web API where the object type being acted on is set by a string parameter.  I then need to call a number of generic methods based on that type. Basically what I have is a good old switch statement that I'm in danger of having to repeat several times over, so want to try to encapsulate it within a reusable method:

```
switch (ModuleName)
            {
                case "contacts":
                    return Method1<Contact>();
                case "accounts":
                    return Method1<Account>();
                default:
                    throw new Exception("ModuleName could not be resolved");
            }
```

In other places I'll need to do the same thing but call Method2, Method3, Method4 etc.

I think I should be able to turn this into a method that takes a string and a delegate that accepts the generic type, but I'm stuck on how to construct that.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Tim

Comment: Generics parameters need to be known at compile time. Basically you will need a switch or a dictionary ect ect ect

Comment: What do each of the methods return? It'd be great to see a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRandall, I realised that I still needed a switch, it was just trying not to repeat the same switch statement multiple times. Thanks Enigmativity I'm a new poster so will do better next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Michael Randall says, generics need to be known at compile time. I think you need to reconsider how you encapsulate your business logic here. You could probably solve it like this:

```
class Example{

    void Main(){

        var method1 = new LogicMethod1();
        TestCase("contacts", method1);
        TestCase("Case2", method1);

        var method2 = new LogicMethod2();
        TestCase("contacts", method2);
        TestCase("Case2", method2);
    }

    void TestCase(string moduleName, LogicBase logic){


        switch(moduleName){
            case "contacts" : logic.DoTheStuff<Contact>(); break;
            case "accounts" : logic.DoTheStuff<Account>(); break;
        }
    }
}

abstract class LogicBase{
    public abstract void DoTheStuff<T>();
}

class LogicMethod1 : LogicBase{
    public override void DoTheStuff<T>(){
        //Logic for your Method1
    }
}

class LogicMethod2 : LogicBase{
    public override void DoTheStuff<T>(){
        //Logic for your Method2
    }
}
```